# How to send bool value from one method to another in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is code to answer an incoming call and the original code just
answered the call automatically.

I am changing it so that when an incoming call is detected, an Answer
button appears, which works (with `[_answerButton setAlpha:1];`), but
then I want to accept the connection by clicking that button. I tried
just moving:

```
    [connection accept];
    _connection = connection;
```

to the answerCall method, but for some reason that didn't work. So now
I just want to add some code that will set a BOOL to true when I click
the answer button and pass that BOOL back to `didAnswerCall` and add an
else if to that method that will accept the connection when it's true.

```
- (IBAction)answerCall:(id)sender {
    // Need code to run didReceiveIncomingConnection method again, 
    // but pass Bool for didAnswerCall that equals true
}

- (void)device:(TCDevice *)device
didReceiveIncomingConnection:(TCConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Incoming connection from: %@", [connection parameters][@"From"]);
    if (device.state == TCDeviceStateBusy) {
        [connection reject];
    }
    // Need else if code in here that says if didAnswerCall is true,
then [connection accept]
    else {
        [_answerButton setAlpha:1];

        //[connection accept];
        //_connection = connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I tried just moving [connection accept]; _connection = connection; to the answerCall method, but for some reason that didn't work." - If this caused your `-answerCall:` method to look like the following:

```
- (IBAction)answerCall:(id)sender {
    [connection accept]; 
    _connection = connection;
}
```

Then it is understandable that it didn't work. In the above code, `connection` has not been declared in the scope of the `-answerCall` method. Calling a method on it doesn't make any sense. In fact, this shouldn't compile.

I don't believe passing a boolean around your class is your best bet. You were on track to succeed by trying to accept the connection in `-answerCall`. All you need is to have your class hold a reference to `connection`. In your `@interface` try adding a property so that an instance of your class can remember `connection`:

```
@interface YourClass()

@property (nonatomic) TCConnection *connection;

// other code ...

@end

@implementation YourClass

- (IBAction)answerCall:(id)sender {
    if (self.connection) {
        [self.connection accept];
    }
}

- (void)device:(TCDevice *)device
didReceiveIncomingConnection:(TCConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Incoming connection from: %@", [connection parameters][@"From"]);
    if (device.state == TCDeviceStateBusy) {
        [connection reject];
    }
    else {
        // remember the connection here
        self.connection = connection;
        [_answerButton setAlpha:1];
    }
}

// other code ...

@end
```

Comment: Thank you SO much Phillip!! This was my first question ever on stackoverflow and your solution worked like a charm!!